# How to transform uilabel keeping its x position same and scale to reduce the font size

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I implemented a navigation header (uiview) which shrinks at the time of scrolling tablview upwards and expands when scrolling down. Exactly same like ubers ios app header in profile page. I am able to change the label position on scrolling from bottom to up right corner but how can i lower the font size on scrolling. If i change the font size dynamically it is jerking. If i use transform scale then i cannot figure the amount by which i need to scale the label to achieve particular font size. when larger uialabel x position is 15 with font size 24 and when collapsed x position will be 45 with font size 20. Any lead will be very much appreciated.

```
func updateHeader() {
    let range = maximumHeaderHeight - minimumHeaderHeight
    let openAmount = headerHeightConstraint.constant - maximumHeaderHeight
    let percentage = openAmount / range
    headerLabelLeadingConstraint.constant = labelXPositionOfAnimationHeader - (openAmount)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Take a View for header & set 6 constraints (So max height of our header will be 100 and minimum height will be 50)**

1. Height == 100 (Priority : 750) **(Create IBOutlet for this constraint)**
2. Height <= 100 (Priority : 1000)
3. Height >= 50 (Priority : 1000)
4. Trailing == 0
5. Leading == 0
6. Top == 0 **(Connect it from status bar)**

**Add a label inside header view & set 4 constraints**

1. Top == 0
2. Leading == 0
3. Trailing == 0
4. Bottom == 0

**Add a Table view  & set 4 constraints**

1. Top == 0 **(Connect it from status bar)**
2. Leading == 0
3. Trailing == 0
4. Bottom == 0

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView : UITableView? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var headerView : UIView? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel : UILabel? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var headerHeightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint? = nil
    private var headerHeight : CGFloat = 100
    private var topInset : CGFloat = 100 // TopInset == headerHeight
    private var maxFontSize : CGFloat = 32 


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // TopInset == headerHeight
        tableView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 100.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        let y = scrollView.contentOffset.y + topInset
        headerHeightConstraint?.constant = headerHeight - y

        let fontSize = (maxFontSize * (headerView?.frame.height ?? 0))/(headerHeight)
        headerLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sunil for your reply... I did same like you told it's working but i want the label to be transform from bottom left to upper right side to be specific i want to transform it from leading 15px to leading 45px with that smaller effect. How can i do it.

Comment: Ok I got it. I have quickly updated the project as per your requirement, I have added some constraint to move label from left to right and bottom to top.  Although I think there must a better way of doing this instead of playing with constraints. https://github.com/sunilbhosale86/DynamicLabelDemo

Comment: Thank you very much Sunil... You saved my day. Perfect answer for me...